# When people download my app from the google play i get this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error

my name is Walid.

im having this error when people download my app from google play i get this error 
i think its when certain devices download the app it causes the app to crash .

this is the sdk in the manifest.

please if anyone knows how to fix this please let me know .

Thank you.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="2"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity  ComponentInfo{tigris.code.oneallah.walid/tigris.code.oneallah.walid.MenuPage}:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tigris.code.oneallah.walid.MenuPage in loader    dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/tigris.code.oneallah.walid-1.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tigris.code.oneallah.walid.MenuPage in            loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/tigris.code.oneallah.walid-1.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Your APK file does not contain a class named `tigris.code.oneallah.walid.MenuPage`. Either the APK is missing the class, or ProGuard renamed it.

Comment: how is that possible , i have that path . i didnt use proGuard, is ProGuard Necessarily ?

Comment: @WalidWilder: "how is that possible" -- I have no good way to answer that. "i didnt use proGuard" -- if you made a release build for the Play Store, you probably did. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: Thanks very much . one last question , what do you recommend i should do to fix this problem cause this is my first time i publish an app and i dont have too much experience .

Comment: @WalidWilder: Read the linked-to material on ProGuard, set up your `proguard-project.txt` to keep the classes in your package(s), build a fresh APK, and try installing it. If it works, release the new edition.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help . This app is based on a  menu that when you click a button it takes you to a new activity which contains two buttons previous and next , and an imageview , the user can move from one picture to another using them buttons . simple as that .